# PHP contact form: disable confirm form resubmission popup when page refresh

Tags: php, forms

**I am trying to create a simple PHP contact form. 
I used header() to redirect to page itself, it blocks the

> confirm form resubmission

popup window. However, the problem is I need to display $result when a user submit the form. The redirection also stop passing $result to the HTML DOM. How can I fix the problem?**

```
  if($name != "" & $email != ""){

    $result = '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    $body = "From: $name\n E-mail: $emial\n Message:\n $message";
    mail($to, $ownSubject, $message, $body);
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].$result);
  }
```

Comment: just create another page so POSTback doesn't occur when you submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this:

```
//Check to see that you received request POST | GET
if( !empty($_REQUEST ))
{
    // if($name != "" & $email != ""){ // This is wrong
    //Use not empty as it check for "" | null | false   
    if( !empty( $name ) && !empty( $email ) )
    {
        $result = '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        $body = "From: $name\n E-mail: $emial\n Message:\n $message";
        mail($to, $ownSubject, $message, $body);
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }   

    var_dump( $result );
}
```

#### HappyCoding

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your `$result` variable in your redirecting url.

```
if($name != "" & $email != ""){
    $result = '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    $body = "From: $name\n E-mail: $emial\n Message:\n $message";
    mail($to, $ownSubject, $message, $body);
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?result='.$result);
}

//this will work after redirecting using your header redirect
if(isset($_GET['result']) && !empty($_GET['result'])) {
    echo $_GET['result'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For redirection try any of the below script.

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].$result);
exit();
```

or

```
echo '<script>location.href= "'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"</script>';
exit();
```